# checkbox in chrome webstore dev dashboard for inline installation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is there any check box for inline installation enable option in web store development dashboard?
If possible, can I have screen-shot ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about developing Chrome extensions, but about publishing extensions in the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see *why* you're asking, but yes, such a checkbox exists on the Edit Item form in Developer Dashboard.

[image: inline install]

Note that to use inline install, you must also fulfill [verified website requirement](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#verified-site).

The "more info" link goes to the same documentation, and "may delay publishing" means that an inline install item has a high score in manual review triggering heuristics.

Comment: Thanks! My problem is solved. I was getting error 'cause my extension publisher had not enabled the checkbox for inline installation.